# "(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action" errors?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

Using the Facebook Graph API explorer with my "user access_token" (contains ads_management, ads_read, read_insights permissions.) call 
`"/v2.5/act_595104887309744/insights"`.

But the following error was produced.

> { "error": { "code": 10, "fbtrace_id": "Avw8isJiSOa", "type":
>   "OAuthException", "message": "(#10) You do not have sufficient
>   permissions to perform this action" } }

my role is "Ad Account Admin" in 595104887309744 ad account.
what is problem? what is my mistake?